# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us to consider holding an election for moderators for Arts & Crafts.

The last election we held was back in 2020, where we elected two moderators, and since then, one moderator (Erica) has expressed the desire to resign, so we will be holding an election for another moderator.

So: we should hold a new election to get ourselves back up to a more regularly-available and active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Currently, February 14th is the tentative date for such an election, starting with nominations, but only if we can get enough people willing to run for moderator positions.

Comment: Can you clarify what mod positions will need to be filled?  Is it just Erica's, or our entire slate?  My understanding is that elected mods serve indefinitely, but mods appointed during a site's beta phase serve only until there is an election.  A&C recently graduated from beta, but the rest of our mod slate was elected.

Comment: We just wanted to add an extra person so we have 3 mods total since Erica will step down. @fixer1234

Answer (score 5):

I will definitely run again.
I'm also hoping for a more active moderator team. Our community still can use a lot of improvements, and with a proactive team that is regularly online that will be a lot easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

I'm willing to run.
I'm also a moderator on [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) and know what to expect.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to run again.
Would like to help the community out as much as possible when needed. Would like proactive approach as well.

Comment: I noticed on your personal web page that you started a new job in February.  Paying the rent can put a drag on your available time.  :-)  The nomination period isn't over yet.  If you still have the time and inclination, I hope you put in your hat again.  If not, thanks for stepping up during the site's previous time of need.  Not many users are willing to.  In either case, hope you still have time to at least remain active.  The fact that you were elected as a moderator recognizes your contributions.